# Nuxt 3 .well-known route

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, cloudflare-workers, nuxtjs3

I'm having a problem getting nuxt3 to serve a /.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association route in production. I'm trying to use static hosting (cloudflare) but when I deploy the project `npx nuxt generate` the route always receives 404. I've tried adding the folder/file to the public directory (404) and also tried registering the file's content as a server route combined with nitro's prerender config, but also no luck...

Annoyingly if I use miniflare to simulate production locally, then run
`npx nuxt build` & `npx nuxt preview` I can access the route.

Also noticed that the /.output/public/_nuxt/entry-[hash].mjs file doesn't seem to be registering the route as it does for all the other assets/pages.

*nuxt.config.ts*

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    
    nitro: {
        preset: 'cloudflare',
        prerender: {
            routes: ['/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association']
        }
    },
    ssr: false,
    target: 'static'
})
```

*/server/routes/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.ts*

```js
import { defineEventHandler } from 'h3'

export default defineEventHandler(() => "92324FSD2FFADAD124RTSDGSDF7B227073704964223A22")
```

Comment: Yes, posting code as images is forbidden. Please use code snippet with actual text + highlighting. Otherwise, [this](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions?discussions_q=public+directory) may be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You can host folders/files in your `static` directory which gets mapped to the root of your app/site. I just did something similar and hosted a .well-known folder for Microsoft like this `/static/.well-known/microsoft-identity-association.json`.

Comment: this doesn't work for static hosting - the route isn't registered into nuxt's entry.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't find a Nuxt solution, I ended up conditionally overriding the request within Cloudflare's Wrangler index.js file. This way it bypasses Nuxt's entry-[hash].js and instead retrieves the resource directly.

```js
async function handleEvent(event) {
  const { pathname } = new URL(event.request.url)

  if(pathname === '/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association'){
    
    const response = await getAssetFromKV(event, {
      mapRequestToAsset: (req) =>
        new Request(`${new URL(req.url).origin}/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.html`, req),
    })

    return new Response(response.body, {...response,})
  }

//
// rest of Nuxt's routing here
//

}
```